# How to use multiple git repositories in one bndtools workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, git, directory, bndtools

I am using eclipse BndTools with a few dedicated workspaces each stored in a single git repo and I've been quite happy sofar.

I've been sharing projects between workspaces by copying them. But recently decided to pull common code into a shared code git repository. In eclipse this is trivial, just use subfolders in your workspace, one per repository.

However to my surprise bndtools demands that I place one cnf project next to my projects in the filebase. At the same time I can only have one cnf project in my workspace. Which effectively means ALL my projects should be peers.

Which in turn means I cannot use multiple git repositories as they cannot share the same directory. Unless I split each project into it's own repository and with 50+ projects this is clearly not where I want to go.

I know eclipse can do this, but is there a way to get bndtools to play ball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which effectively means ALL my projects should be peers.
> ...
>
> Which in turn means I cannot use multiple git repositories as they cannot share the same directory. Unless I split each project into it's own repository

This is where submodule is coming for rescue.

> ***`Submodules`*** ***allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a dedicated subdirectory*** of the source tree, always pointed at a particular commit.

[image]

---

#### ***`How to use submodules`***

```
# Create each project in its own repository

# now add the desired submodule to your project
git submodule add <url>

# now init/update one by one or recursively all at once
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Comment: Thank you CodeWizard. I'm hoping for a solution that does not require me to initalize a git repo for every project in my workspace. But it is good to know that if I must go that path at least Git has me covered.

Comment: Using submodule the content is a root repository and each submodule can be shared. Another way it to use sub-tree which is more or less the same.

Comment: I am trying this out, but this seems to be built for upstream changes, external libraries you might want to include. But since those libraries are not external for me I want to change them quite heavily. My naive experiments ended up in a detached head in one of the submodules. I'm not done experimenting. But I do understand you correctly when you say this will work in pushing changes upstream as if I'm working in a single repository?

Comment: Yep. each submodule is a standalone repository, having its own branches, tags etc. You simply pull the desired version (or latest) and when you work on it you can commit as usual. The pint is that if you make changes when executing `git status` on the parent folder you will not see the changes since its a standalone repo.

Comment: And as far as I understand this is not the only problem. Any change in a submodule requires me to cd into that submodule, commit by hand and push. Though there is a shortcut to push all submodules since earlier this year. But since changes can easily affect any of the 50+ repositories that's going to add a prohibitve amount of overhead. I don't think submodules will solve my problem. But thank you for your suggestion I do know a little more about Git now than I knew when I started the day...

Comment: You can do a balk command on all the submodules at once. This is not an issue, " I don't think submodules will solve my problem". I dont seenay other answer to your question, The problem is that you have 50+ folders.

Glad to help and to teach you new stuff.